# How to join several list interleaving with some fixed list between?

Tags: list-manipulation

How to join several list putting some fixed list between?

Like this

```
MyJoin[{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}},{x}]
```

giving

```
{a, b, x, c, d, x, e, f}
```

This is like join with connector.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Riffle` and `Join`:

```
MyJoin[list_,glue_] := Join @@ Riffle[list, {glue}]
```

or as a pure function

```
MyJoin = Join @@ Riffle[#, {#2}] &
```

Comment: The exhibited function does not work for the example shown in the question.  This is because `Riffle` interprets a list in the second argument as a cyclic replacement specification.  The second argument must be wrapped in a list to work around this interpretation: `MyJoin[list_,glue_] := Join @@ Riffle[list, {glue}]` or `MyJoin = Join @@ Riffle[#, {#2}] &`.

Comment: @WReach Oh, good catch, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
MyJoin = Flatten@*Riffle;

MyJoin[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {x}]
(*{a, b, x, c, d, x, e, f}*)
```

As Martin Büttner pointed out, this will flatten internal structures in nested lists, which may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: What is "@*"? Can't find it

Comment: @SuzanCioc It's function composition. Note that using `Flatten` will not preserve any structure within your initial list (i.e. if either argument contains nested lists, those will be flattened as well).

Comment: @MartinBüttner: It's actually new in Mathematica 2 :)

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Oh... then I only discovered it recently. (Ah, `RightComposition` aka `/*` is what's new in 10.)

Comment: Apparently it existing but not shortened to "@*" in my Mathematica.

Comment: The `@*` sigil for `Composition` is new in 10. Otherwise this would be written as `Flatten~Composition~Riffle` (in infix form).